# how to use the ref.view-model feature

Tags: aurelia

I'm seeing this feature in the docs, but I can't quite figure out how to use it from that information.

It says:

`<i-produce-a-value ref.view-model="producer"></i-produce-a-value>
<i-consume-a-value input.bind="producer.output"></i-consume-a-value>`

What does this look like in real world example?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This syntax has actually changed to be more consistent with the rest of Aurelia's binding syntax in our latest release (which hit after you posted this question).

The syntax is now:

```
<i-produce-a-value view-model.ref="producer"></i-produce-a-value>
<i-consume-a-value input.bind="producer.output"></i-consume-a-value>
```

But anyways, `view-model.ref="producer"` creates an alias to the view-model for the `i-produce-a-value` custom element which you can then use elsewhere to pass to another custom element or use properties of the VM. Thus in the second line of the code above, `i-consume-a-value` has a property called `input` that has been bound to the `output` property of the VM of the `i-produce-a-value` element.

Let's look at an example. Say you have a `DatePicker` custom element. Its view model has several properties such as `dayOfWeek` and `month`. You would like to use the properties in other elements on your view. You could bind a property on your View's VM to each of these properties and then bind to your View's properties elsewhere in your view where you want to use these values, or you can use the `view-model.ref` to allow you to bind directly to these values on your `DatePicker` custom element. Something like this:

```
<date-picker value.bind="eventDate" 
             view-model.ref="eventDateVM"></date-picker>
<div>
  <p>Event Month: ${eventDateVM.month}</p>
  <p>Event Day of Week: ${eventDateVM.dayOfWeek}</p>
  <img src.bind="eventDateVM.dayInHistoryImageUrl" />
</div>
```

So, in this example, we have bound the value property of the `DatePicker` to the `eventDate` property of our page's VM. More importantly, we have created an alias to the VM of the `DatePicker` custom element and named it `eventDateVM`. We then use this alias to display the month and day of week for the date picked in the custom element. This imaginary `DatePicker` also has a VM property that is set to the url for a picture of something that happened on the date chosen, so we bind that url to the `src` property of an `img` tag.

Let me know if you have any more questions about this very powerful feature of Aurelia!

Comment: In your example, what would be the difference if I were to change  value.bind="eventDate" to ref="eventDate" ?

Comment: wow thank you for the detailed explanation, I would suggest adding a practical example like this to the docs

Comment: @ChiRow `value.bind="eventDate"` binds the `value` property of the `DatePicker` to the `eventDate` property of the parent ViewModel. `ref="eventDate"` creates an alias `eventDate` that contains the DOM element for the `DatePicker` custom element. This is a huge difference. You're not getting the bindable properties, just the DOM element.

Comment: @AshleyGrant Thanks for the explanation.  Does the alias for 'ref' exist in the parent ViewModel as a property even it's not created by the code?

Comment: I just noticed I never answered this question. So, 18 months late I'll answer. Yes. Aurelia will add a property to the parent VM even if it isn't in the VM's code.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update: in Aurelia 2 the syntax [has changed to](https://docs.aurelia.io/developer-guides/migrating-to-aurelia-2#compose)

```
<i-produce-a-value component.ref="producer"></i-produce-a-value>
```